# useInfiniteQuery customization

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have to customize useInfiniteQuery from reactQuery in order to get data from all the pages.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-http-zjpff?file=/pages/index.js:961-1025
This is the sandbox implementation available in the documentation in case you need further context on it.

My Api response looks like this.

```
{
 list:{
       data1: {...data},
       data2: {...data},
       ...
      }
 totalPages: 3,
 totalCount: 15,
 limit: 5
}
```

Here data1, data2 are just examples of data returning in the list and backend is returning the data in pages, every page is unique.

What I have written yet.

```
export const useGetAllContactUsRequest = (
    limit = 10,
    unread = false
): UseInfiniteQueryResult<GetAllContactUsRequestResponse, AxiosError> => {
    let page = 1;
    return useInfiniteQuery(
        ["getAllContactUsRequest", unread],
        ({ pageParam = page }) => getAllContactUsRequest(pageParam, limit, unread),
        {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
                console.log(page);
                page++;
                return lastPage.totalPages >= page ? page : undefined;
            },
        }
    );
};
```

Essentially what I want is to increment the page and get data until the last page available that is `page = 3` in my case.

This is how I am consuming it.

```
const {
        data: readList,
        isSuccess: readListSuccess,
        hasNextPage: readListHasNextPage,
        fetchNextPage: readListFetchNextPage,
    } = useGetAllContactUsRequest();

console.log(readListHasNextPage);
```

This is a function only triggered when the user scrolls at the bottom of the page.

```
const onScrollLoadMore = () => {
  if (readListHasNextPage) {
      readListFetchNextPage();
  }
}
```

The current behavior is that it randomly consoles the page numbers from 1 to 4 and `hasNextPage` criteria always return true.

I need help, it will be appreciated greatly! I have followed up on the documentation and it is confusing.

Comment: not quite sure how to help here, multiple things are confusing to me: 1) the let page in the hook will be re-initialized every render, so you'd need a `useRef` for that. 2) the api response looks like your backend is returning all pages? or what is list1 and list2 inside list? maybe a real-world example would help. 3) are you calling readListFetchNextPage() directly in the render function? most of these questions have little to do with react-query per se, and more with react, side-effects and how the api response is structured :)

Comment: Yes, it is directly in the render function and I have updated the question, hope it helps!

Comment: You can’t call functions that perform side effects like data fetching directly in the render function. Render functions need to be pure.

Comment: I am following the function-based approach and the call is made inside a custom hook!

Comment: doesn't matter if it's custom hook or not - you need to call side-effects like data-fetching in `useEffect`. but what this will achieve is loading of all pages, one after the other. is that what you want? usually, with infinite queries, people want to load the next page when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page or so ...

Comment: That is What I am doing, I made some corrections to the question, My apologies for not giving enough information.
I am essentially calling the load more function only when the user gets to the bottom of the page.